# Material Dialog: Managing Z-index on click event with multiple Dialog instances

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, z-index

I have implemented a service to open and keep open multiple windows using the basic features offered by Angular Material (MatDialogModule). 
Everything works fine, but I can't find a way to manage the z-index of the windows every time the user clicks between them. 
The incriminated element in this case is the wrapper "cdk-global-overlay-wrapper" that is duplicated keeping a static z-index of "1000" leaving the priority of visualization to the position in the DOM of the added dialog element.

I've seen that the thing becomes viable if I develop a personal service passing from the cdk "overlay" but in this case i will lose all the immediate features and properties of the Dialog proposed by Material.

Is there a way? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically updating the z-index of multiple cdkDialogs or matDialogs can be done with the following snippet (Angular v14):

```js
// app/dialog.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DialogService {
  private $zIndex = 1000;

  constructor(
    private $dialog: Dialog, // import from cdk/dialog or mat/dialog
  ) { }


  openDialog(uniqueDialogId: string) {
    // this brings already open dialogs to the top of all
    if(this.$dialog.getDialogById(uniqueDialogId)) {
      this.setFocus(uniqueDialogId);
      return;
    }

    // create a new dialog
    this.$dialog.open(
      MyCustomDialogComponent,
      {
        id: myUniqueDialogId, // required
        data: {id: myUniqueDialogId} // required for z-index and dragable
        hasBackdrop: false, // required
        panelClass: 'drag-target-' + idContributionDialog // required for dragable
      }
    );
    
    // this focuses new dialogs
    this.setFocus(myUniqueDialogId);
  }


  setFocus(uniqueDialogId: string) {
    const dialog = this.$dialog.getDialogById(uniqueDialogId);
    dialog?.overlayRef.hostElement.style.setProperty('z-index', (this.$zIndex++).toString());
  }
}
```

```js
// app/my-custom-dialog.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-custom-dialog',
  template: `
    <!-- enable drag -->
    <div [cdkDragRootElement]="'.drag-target-' + data!.id"
     cdkDrag
     cdkDragHandle
   >
      content goes here
   </div>
  `,
})
export class MyCustomDialogComponent {

  // capture click (mousedown) event and set focus to the clicked dialog 
  @HostListener('mousedown') setFocus() {
    this.$dialogService.setFocus(this.data!.id);
  }

  constructor(
    @Inject(DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private $dialogService: DialogService,
  )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use following css class :
to manipulate the z index

```
.cdk-overlay-container{
  z-index: 9997;
}
```